# c++/winRT Navigation between two pages

Tags: c++-winrt

I'm attempting to navigate from a page (SettingsPage) to another page (Page1). Here's what  tried:

```
this->Frame::Navigate(typeid(Page1))
```

And I get this error - Error (active)   E0244   qualified name is not a member of class "winrt::Calculator::implementation::SettingsPage" or its base classes   ...

My question - what is the proper way to make this call.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [xaml_typename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/xaml-typename) function template to get an object that suitably describes a type to XAML (as a [TypeName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.interop.typename) struct) in C++/WinRT. Make sure to pass an appropriately qualified type, e.g.

```cpp
this->Frame().Navigate(xaml_typename<Page1>());
```

Make sure to `#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop.h>` which defines the `xaml_typename` function template.

Note that `Frame` is a property of `Page`, that's accessed using parentheses in C++/WinRT. Also note that [Navigate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.navigate) is a non-static class member, so you cannot use the scope resolution operator (`::`).